# How to use PDO::FETCH_SERIALIZE correctly?

Tags: php, pdo

I've tried to implement code that uses `PDO::FETCH_SERIALIZE` to automatically unserialize php object from database.

I've checked the documentation and the [corresponding php test](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_mysql/tests/pdo_mysql_stmt_fetch_serialize.phpt) which looks basically the same to what I have:

```
class foo implements Serializable {
    private $data;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->data = "My private data";
    }
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize($this->data);
    }
    public function unserialize($data) {
        $this->data = unserialize($data);
    }
    public function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
$foo = new foo;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT \'C:3:"foo":23:{s:15:"My private data";}\' foo');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_SERIALIZE, 'foo');
$data = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($data);
```

But it still unserializes it into something not what one expects. The result of running of this code is

```
object(foo)#4 (1) {
  ["data":"foo":private]=>
  object(foo)#5 (1) {
    ["data":"foo":private]=>
    string(15) "My private data"
  }
}
```

whereas one wouldn't expect an object to be nested. As it should be

```
object(foo)#2 (1) {
  ["data":"foo":private]=>
  string(15) "My private data"
}
```

instead.

What am I missing?

**UPD 1**:

I just tried using a real table instead of hardcoded data. It changed nothing. The current code is crafted especially so that everyone could run it without creating test database/tables to check it.

**UPD 2**:

Alias name changes nothing and effectively may be completely omitted.

**UPD 3**:

I have created a bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68802, let's see if php dev team accepts it.

Comment: did you try inserting into the db the result of `serialize($foo)` to make sure? It looks like your select is hand crafted

Comment: @Sebas I have. It's the same (it doesn't surprise me much though - it's that data matters, not its source). Also added an update

Comment: Just as an initial guess, I'd say the alias "foo" is throwing it off somehow

Comment: @Phil tried to change it as well. Alias may be omitted or changed to anything without any changes in behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are serializing entire object in your hand crafted query.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT \'C:3:"foo":23:{s:15:"My private data";}\' foo');
```

Should be:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT \'s:15:"My private data";\' foo');
```

Simply because `foo::serialize` returns `s:15:"My private data";` and not entire serialized object, later on, same serialized string gets injected into `foo::unserialize`, thus in your case, `$data instanceof foo` instead of string.

Output as you've expected:

```
object(foo)#4 (1) {
  ["data":"foo":private]=>
  string(15) "My private data"
}
```

Comment: `serialize($foo)` outputs `C:3:"foo":23:{s:15:"My private data";}` and in php test they do perform explicit `serialize`

Comment: I see, in their test they do not check that it's possible to assemble an object back. They simply don't check it

Comment: :p I have no memory of this statement :p